# Where is Goshen?

Tags: genesis, geography, egypt

In Genesis 45:10 (NASB)

> For you shall live in the land of **Goshen**, and you shall be near me (...)

Where is Goshen?

Comment: In New York, up past Warwick a ways. :)

Comment: @hobbs funny Andrew !

Comment: It's in Indiana, just southeast of Elkhart.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica who would be the Joseph living near? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *The New Ungers Bible Dictionary* under the term **GO'SHEN** page 492 and 493

> 1. A northeastern section of the Egyptian Delta region usually called "the land of Goshen," "country of Goshen" (Gen. 45:10; Josh. 10:41),
>    or simply "Goshen" (Gen. 47:27) and "the land of Rameses" (47:11; cf.
>    Ex. 12:37). In this region the Israelites under Jacob settled during
>    the time Joseph was prime minister (Gen. 46:28-34). This was a fertile
>    section of Egypt, excellent for grazing and certain types of
>    agriculture, but apparently not particularly inviting to the pharaohs
>    because of its distance from the Nile irrigation canals. It extends
>    thirty of forty miles in length, centering in Wadi Tumilat, and
>    reaches from Lake Times to the Nile. It was connected with the name
>    Rameses because Rameses II (c. 1290-1224 B.C.) built extensively in
>    this location at Within (Tell el Retabah) and Rameses (Tell ed-dab'a).
>    Tanis was called the House of Rameses (c. 1300-1100 B.C.). Therefore,
>    the term *Raamses* in Ex. 1:11 must be construed as being a
>    modernization of an archaic place name and as having reference to an
>    earlier city Zoan-Tanis, where the Israelites laborer centuries
>    earlier.
>
> [image: GO'SHEN in The New Ungers Bible Dictionary]
>
> (...)

Comment: If it was not inviting to the Pharaohs, how did Moses end up in the hands of the Pharaoh's daughter? I've been trying to figure out how Pharaoh's daughter ended up finding Moses, with this location of Goshen. Surely Moses would have floated downstream, into the Sea, rather than upstream towards the more Egyptian districts, including the capital, whichever city that was at the time

Answer (score 0):

**Where is Goshen?**

A region in Egypt where the Israelites resided for over 200 years,the location is not certain, but it is believed to be in the vicinity of Wadi  Tumilat.

https://www.google.com/search?q=wadi+tumilat+map&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Nbus_kuInPZPOM%252CAv_VJ5TM2ASaEM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTuBK3o3ul7QZpAg9jjS6OQH6P-MA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAuZqwm6DuAhViTRUIHZfsC-oQ9QF6BAgKEAE&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=Nbus_kuInPZPOM

Genesis 45:10 NASB

> 10 For you shall live in the land of Goshen, and you shall be near me,
> you and your children and your [a]grandchildren, and your flocks and
> your herds and all that you have.